# DynamoDb can't add item to table

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm struggling writing to a DynamoDb database from a lambda function.  The code, below, gets to the "In try" message.  I get neither "save" or "fail".  Oh and no data gets written to the dynamodb table.  Was kind of expecting, wrong key, wrong permissions, anything really.

nsProp is a c# object and has data,
table key is Site,
range key is SignupDate.

Thanks in advance

```
var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
            accessKey: accessKey,
            secretKey: secretKey);

        var config = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig
        {
            RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest2           
        };

        Console.WriteLine("After config");
        AmazonDynamoDBClient newclient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials, config);
        var NewContext = new DynamoDBContext(client);

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In try");

            PutItemResponse x = await newclient.PutItemAsync(
                tableName: tableName,

                item: new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
                {
                        {"Site", new AttributeValue {S = nsProp.Site}},
                        {"SignupDate", new AttributeValue {S = nsProp.SignupDate}},
                        {"Email", new AttributeValue {S = nsProp.Email}}
                }
            );
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            //await context.SaveAsync<NewsletterSignupProp>(nsProp);

            Console.WriteLine("Save");
            return "Save";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fail" + ex.Message);
            return "Fail";
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in debug mode?

Comment: Is tableName, the string, defined? I can't see it.

Comment: Yes Rob, a few lines above.

Comment: I have solved this - back to basics with a console app and stepping through on the debugger.